# Why can't an ASP.NET MVC strongly typed view use an interface?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why can't I use this interface to create a strongly typed view?

```
public interface IAmAnAsset
{
    int assetID { get; }
    String assetTag { get; set; }
    int? AddedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime addedDate { get; set; }
    int? LocationId { get; set; }
    DateTime? purchasedDate { get; set; }
    int? purchasedby { get; set; }
    DateTime? disposalDate { get; set; }
    int assetModelId { get; set; }
    int? employeeId { get; set; }
    float? depreciated { get; set; }
    IAmAComputer Computer { get;  }
}
```

When I take that exact item and convert to an abstract class, it lets me create a strongly typed view.

I'm new but I would imagine there's something I'm missing, ASP.NET MVC can work with interfaces, right?

Here's the specific class in the persistence layer I'm trying to make use of to create a strongly typed view.

```
public class ModelAsset : BufferedLinqEntity2<LqGpsDataContext, asset>, AssetManagementModel.IAmAnAsset
{
...
}
```

I'm trying to create my first MVC view.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC does support strongly typed views using interfaces. What particular issues do you have?

Comment: I can't have a data layer class that inherits some data-based behavior, while implementing the model layer interface that I want to show on a view.

Comment: I think maybe you misread Darin's comment. ASP.NET MVC **DOES** support interfaces. Please can elaborate with the abstract class and master page snippet? Thanks.

Comment: See [this blog post](http://blog.davidohara.net/2009/08/18/using-interfaces-for-model-in-asp-net-mvc-impl/) for more information on implementing strongly typed views in ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: @Dan does it support interfaces as the source of a strongly typed view?

Comment: when I right click my folder 'Asset' and select create view, how come this interface is not available as the strongly-typed View data class?

Comment: So don't use the wizzard, just change the type that the view inherits from in the code.

Comment: @Sosh when I did that it did not autogenerate the layouts with their fields for me.

Comment: I read that post and the one that brought him about to writing the one you linked, and I am not understanding them.

Comment: @Maslow: you should post the minimal code.

Comment: @user596314 - there isn't any code related to the Visual studio designer not allowing you to select an interface, besides the interface code I included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I wound up doing is temporarily changing IAmAnAsset to an abstract class long enough so that the Create View drop down had it available,used that to create the View, then switched it back so the persistance/database layer would compile again.

Here's what it generated for me:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<AssetManagementModel.IAmAnAsset>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Assets
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<h2>ListAll</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            assetID
        </th>
        <th>
            assetTag
        </th>
        <th>
            AddedBy
        </th>
        <th>
            addedDate
        </th>
        <th>
            LocationId
        </th>
        <th>
            purchasedDate
        </th>
        <th>
            purchasedby
        </th>
        <th>
            disposalDate
        </th>
        <th>
            assetModelId
        </th>
        <th>
            employeeId
        </th>
        <th>
            depreciated
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.assetID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.assetTag) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.AddedBy) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.addedDate)) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LocationId) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.purchasedDate)) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.purchasedby) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.disposalDate)) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.assetModelId) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.employeeId) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.depreciated) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>

<p>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I had to do this for the index, create and edit pages. Since if left as an interface it did not autogenerate any of the properties.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET works perfectly fine with interfaces:

```
public interface IAmAnAsset
{
    int AssetID { get; set; }
}

public class AmAnAsset : IAmAnAsset
{
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IAmAnAsset model = new AmAnAsset { AssetID = 10  };
        return View(model);
    }
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IAmAnAsset>" %>

<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p><%= Model.AssetID %></p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: When I go to create view, my controller is not listed as a source for a strongly typed view?

Comment: How do you create your views? I've never used the ASP.NET MVC wizard for adding strongly typed views. Maybe your interface model type is not listed in the combobox? If this is the case just create your view manually as I did in my example.

Comment: You mean that your INTERFACE is not listed? That doesn't matter, just replace the Inherits template directive manually in your view.

Comment: @Maslow Why would your controller be the source type for the view?

Comment: doesn't creating a view in the controller violate the whole point of mvc? to break things apart into distinct layers?

Comment: @Dan - I'm trying to make sense of Darin's example and how it fits into the MVC framework

Comment: @Maslow, you don't create a view in your controller. You create a model which is passed to the view for rendering. That's the point of MVC.

Comment: @Darin - re:how do I create my views. This is my first view, I'm right clicking the asset folder I created in the views folder and selecting the View item.

Comment: @darin re: creating a view in your controller. I'm trying to create a strongly typed view, does your answer pertain to that?